# Jaggery JS Convert WSRequest to JSON

Tags: javascript, wso2, javascript-framework, jaggery-js

I am calling a data service from a jaggery js app using http://jaggeryjs.org/apidocs/ws.jag .  The data comes back in XML with members .responseText and .responseE4X.  Is there an easy way to convert this response to JSON?  Is there a parameter I can set to have this respond with JSON?  This is being run in the server side, so I do not have access to window(), which most XML to JSON converters use.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, E4X appears to be bugged:  is returns undefined in code and in the "try it" service:  http://jaggeryjs.org/apidocs/xml.jag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by using the post method:  http://jaggeryjs.org/apidocs/post.jag

It is worth noting that there is a bug in this as well.  I had to set the content type header as "content-type" and not "Content-Type".

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you did this using post method?